# Mongodb full text search with sort by timestamp?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, full-text-search

I've literally researched the entire web and couldn't find a satisfactory answer for this so thought I would ask here.

Basically what I'm trying to do is build a full text search query with pagination, which returns results sorted by time.

The problem is, a naive sort like the following doesn't perform at all:

```
db.collection
  .find({ $text: { $search: "hello" } })
  .sort({ created_at: -1 })
  .limit(100)
  .toArray(function(....
```

And yes, I've of course indexed it with `created_at`. And as you can see it's limited to 100 items.

So far what I gather is that the full text index in MongoDB doesn't let you sort by any arbitrary attribute in the collection AT ALL, and the only way to sort it is by adding some `$meta` attribute to sort it based on some internal scoring mechanism.

But that doesn't work for me, and i really want to sort this by `created_at`.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the whole thing, but I refuse to believe that no one has come up with a solution for this very obvious use case. Am I missing something? Does anyone know how to sort a large text search result by a collection attribute? At this point I would appreciate ANY shine of light, even if it's a hack.

[EDIT] For example without the limit and sort, the response would look something like this:

```
[{
  "msg": "hello world",
  "created_at": 1000
}, {
  "msg": "hello",
  "created_at": 899
}, {
  "msg": "hello hello",
  "created_at": 1003
}, {
  ...
}]
```

But I want to limit it to only 100, sorted by `created_at`, AFTER having searched the database for the occurrrence of "hello". I don't care about relevance and I only want to sort so that it's ordered by time.

```
[{
  "msg": "hello hello",
  "created_at": 1003
}, {
  "msg": "hello world",
  "created_at": 1000
}, {
  "msg": "hello",
  "created_at": 899
}, {
  ...
}]
```

Just to be clear, the query DOES work, but it takes very long time even though I have indexed it with `created_at`. I don't have this issue when I do a similar find-sort-limit pattern with other queries (not full text search), and I think this is specific to full text search.

I am looking for a way to somehow make this query faster.

Comment: Looks like you are misunderstanding some things so I suggest you clarify some points. Show a small sample of data in your question and what you are expecting to happen. The general concept of sorting a "text search" result by anything other than "relevance" generally does not make a lot of sense. Relevance ***then*** by "secondary" sorting parameters, makes *somewhat* more sense, but in practical usage terms that would generally be *little* difference.

Comment: "The general concept of sorting a "text search" result by anything other than "relevance" generally does not make a lot of sense."

==> Why do you think all search engines need to be sorted by "relevance"? There are plenty of search options in every search features around the web, such as sort by latest, sort by alphabetical order, etc. Are you saying MongoDB shouldn't support searches sorted by time or ABC?

Comment: Huh? Why are you arguing back my exact point? YOU are the one saying "I don't want relevance". If you think you don't mean that then please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53126109/edit) with the sample data and expected result in order to make your position "clearer", just like you were nicely asked to do but still have not yet done.

Comment: I'm sorry that I came off as sounding confrontational, I didn't mean to. But I still don't understand your point and that's why I can't update the post, because i don't know how. Yes, I am the one saying "I don't want relevance". I want to sort by time. Unless you regard sorting by time as "relevance" I don't think I'm arguing back your point. Could you clarify what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: How about you take the time to read the comment, and instead of reacting and posting more comments you actually [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53126109/edit) to show an example of what you expect. Not looking for a discussion here, but simply looking for a "clear" set of expectations so you can be pointed to the right thing to do.

Comment: ok i added more description and example, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: So what does `.find({ "$text": { "$search": "hello" } },{ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" }, created_at: -1 } )` produce then? That means you return relevance first and then order by date. Effectively there just isn't going to be much difference unless multiple things show the same relevance score. Hence I'm asking you to "project" that as well so yo can see it clearly. It's also a requirement of sorting that you project the meta property as well, AFAIK

Comment: Side note. Pretty sure this is okay with `$text` operations since I don't believe there is an inherent "limit" to the relevance response. It's a bit different for geospatial queries though since those have a built in limit parameter to the "nearest" results which can effect other query conditions and of course additional use of `limit()`

Comment: @AlexBlex Correct me if I'm wrong, but my interpretation of the documentation you linked was that you can't sort based on the way text index is created. It explicitly says "sort operations cannot use the ordering in the text index." BTW as I mentioned, the sorting DOES work, the problem I'm facing is the performance.

Comment: Ah, indeed, it uses text, then sort generator. When you do text search it have to use text index, not the one for created_at field. Check it with `explain("executionStats")`. You can't use hint to change this behaviour: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#text-search-and-hints.